# hardlink/softlink multiple file to one file

Tags: symlink, cat, hard-link

I have many files in a folder. I want to concatenate all these files to a single file. For example cat * > final_file; But this will increase disk space and also will consume time. Is there is a way where I can hardlink/softlink all the files to final_file? For example ln * final_file.

Comment: Related: [Virtual file made out of smaller ones (for mac-like sparse bundle solution)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59737) and [How to split a ddrescue disk image and how to use it again?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56926)

Comment: You could use FUSE for this task. I've created a simple example on how to accomplish this: [cat-fuse](https://github.com/MrQubo/cat-fuse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With links, I'm afraid, this will not  be possible. However, you could use a
named pipe. Example:

```
# create some dummy files
echo alpha >a
echo beta  >b
echo gamma >c

# create named pipe
mkfifo allfiles

# concatenate files into pipe
cat a b c >allfiles
```

The last call will block until some process reads from the pipe and then exit. For a continuous operation one can use a loop, which waits for a process to read and starts over again.

```
while true; do
  cat a b c >allfiles
done
```

Comment: Wouldn't `cat` block until a process starts reading from the named pipe?

Comment: @JosephR. Yes, it would. Append `&` if that's not desired.

Comment: Great. But wouldn't the OP need to repeat these steps every time he/she wants to access the full content via `allfiles`?

Comment: Indeed. Use `while true; do cat a b c >allfiles; done` if that's not desired.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me (I'm still grappling with the fifo concept). I think your notes should be added to the answer as the OP might not be aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

N files mean N inodes. Hard links, by definition, are simply different names for the same inode. Symlinks are files that point to a certain inode (their target). Either way, soft or hard, the link can refer to a single inode.

Answer (score 2):

In a straight way, no ...
You cannot hard/soft link to a single file. links are nothing more and nothing less than pointer from one file to another.

Now if you are worried about space and want to release the space you can do the following:

```
for i in *
do
    cat < "$i" >> destination_file &&
      rm -f -- "$i"
done
```

Basically, it will append the output to destination_file and remove the file afterwards. Also I'm assuming you don't need the original files.

Comment: Why do you parse `ls`? Just use `for i in *`. And why the loop in the first place? Just do `cat * >> destination`.

Comment: Why not quote the variable (`"$i"`) to allow for spaces in the file name?

Comment: @JosephR. That doesn't help. If you have special characters it'll break.

Comment: @Marco But it would at least help with filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: @Marco I'm not talking about the `ls` part. I agree with you that it's unnecessary (and incorrect). I meant to use the double quotes _as well as_ `for i in *`.

Comment: @JosephR. No, it would not. The quoting is applied too late. The string is already split at the spaces and the individual parts assigned to `i`.

Comment: @JosephR. Sorry, I misunderstood you. Totally! `cat $i` would not work at all, regardless of `*` or `ls`.

Comment: @Marco in the OP he's worried about space. otherwise cat * >> destination was more than enough ... hence the loop to cat and remove the file.

Comment: @AlexandreAlves My point is: i) This loop is terrible. ii) It it totally unnecessary. Just use `cat * >dest` followed by `rm !(dest)` (bash) or `rm ^dest` (zsh).

Comment: @Marco 1st why is terrible? 2nd, from my point of view you are assuming that he OP has small files. if you have 10 files of 1G each and want to cat in a single one you need extra 10G if you only have 7G available cat * > dest_file will not work due to lack of space.

Comment: @AlexandreAlves For starters, you were trying to parse the output of `ls`, which [you shouldn't](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).